# Has anyone integrated Salesforce Commerce Cloud (SFCC) with any messaging technologies?

Tags: salesforce, cloud, commerce

I'm looking for examples of how others might have solved for this.

Did you build a custom cartridge?

Did you leverage some externally running agent to retrieve data by OCAPI (or Commerce Cloud APIs)? ...(i.e., a "pull" strategy)

I've read the documentation, spent many nights searching Google, searched the Salesforce Commerce Cloud Marketplace, spoken with several Salesforce Commerce Cloud expert consultants & system integration firms - but it appears ***no one*** is aware of anyone else doing this before.

Answer (score 1):

Yes I was able to create a custom cartridge for Twilio.
Twilio provides many separate REST APIs for sending text messages, making phone calls, looking up phone numbers, managing your accounts, and a whole lot more.

You can go through their REST API documentation https://www.twilio.com/docs/sms/api. You can use their REST APIs and implement it in Salesforce B2C Commerce.

Follow creating a simple web service in Salesforce B2C Commerce.
https://documentation.b2c.commercecloud.salesforce.com/DOC1/topic/com.demandware.dochelp/content/b2c_commerce/topics/web_services/b2c_coding_your_web_service.html